# Tensorflow gpu not being used though visibly available

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I recently used

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
```

to disable the use of my gpu in tensorflow. However when I came to re-enable it by using **unset CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES** in terminal. Next time I ran I came into this error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation Conv_1_bn_1/gamma/Initializer/ones: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '' because the node {{colocation_node Conv_1_bn_1/gamma/Initializer/ones}} was colocated with a group of nodes that required incompatible device '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0'. All available devices [/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0].

and

> Root Member(assigned_device_name_index_=-1 requested_device_name_='/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0' assigned_device_name_='/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0' resource_device_name_='/device:GPU:0' supported_device_types_=[CPU, XLA_CPU] possible_devices_=[]

I know my gpu is available from

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

which returns

```
.......

incarnation: 351568001108855942
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 5729157120
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
```

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow and tensorflowgpu. I will be very grateful for any and all help - thanks.

Comment: This is a bit weird, it says `physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"`. So it's seeing your CPU as a GPU? Was this the same description of the GPU you got before this issue?

Comment: Did you install the gpu version of tensorflow?

Comment: @Lau yes I have tensorfliw gpu

Comment: @thushv89 yes same with the gpu

Comment: What GPU model do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue I now place this line of code at the top

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 1}))
```

and from now on I will only disable the gpu by using

```
{'GPU': 0}
```

I highly suggest using this as an alternative to os.environ